# Unable to call a available function in addAnnotation of WKInterfaceMap class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

The following is the snippet of the code :

```
    class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {
           @IBOutlet var lastLocation: WKInterfaceMap!
    func A(){       
           let point = MKPointAnnotation()
           point.coordinate = (location?.coordinate)!; // location is a CLLocation variable
           point.title = "Where am I?";
           point.subtitle = "I'm here!!!";
           self.lastLocation.addAnnotation(point, WKInterfaceMapPinColor.Red)
    }

    }
```

This leads to throw an error : Missing argument for parameter 'centerOffset' in call

Now if I add the centre offset to the last line as follows

self.lastLocation.addAnnotation(point, "1", CGPoint.zeroPoint)

it throws an extra argument error.

I am confused whether this is a bug in Xcode.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're on the latest Xcode 6.2.

That said, the definition you are trying to use is:

```
func addAnnotation(_ location: CLLocationCoordinate2D, withPinColor pinColor: WKInterfaceMapPinColor)
```

You are supplying `point` for the first parameter, which is a `MKPointAnnotation`. It is expecting a `CLLocationCoordinate2D`, so use `point.coordinate` instead.

This worked for me (in the playground):

```
import UIKit
import WatchKit

class InterfaceController : WKInterfaceController
{
    var map : WKInterfaceMap!
    var location : CLLocation!

    func foo()
    {
        let point = MKPointAnnotation()
        point.coordinate = location.coordinate
        point.title = "Where am I?"
        point.subtitle = "I'm here!!!"

        self.map.addAnnotation(point.coordinate, withPinColor: .Red)
    }
}
```